# Table optimize command crashed MySQL server

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

I have a large 5GB table on one of my MySQL databases that I wanted to `optimize`.

I went into the console and ran the optimize command and since it's an InnoDB database it cloned the table to a temporary one (is that accurate?).

Anyways, I did not notice that I don't have enough space on my HD to complete this action so it failed in the middle of it:

```
+------------------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table            | Op       | Msg_type | Msg_text                                                          |
+------------------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| support.exported | optimize | note     | Table does not support optimize, doing recreate + analyze instead |
| support.exported | optimize | error    | The table '#sql-420a_65fb' is full                                |
| support.exported | optimize | status   | Operation failed                                                  |
+------------------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now, my HD is 100% full since the temporary table that was created ate up all the storage I had left and I don't have **any** files I can delete from other locations on the HD to free the space.

I tried to restart the mysql daemon since I thought that might initiate a `drop` to the temporary table that was created and that way it will free some space, but what now happens is that I cannot start the server:

```
MySQL Daemon failed to start.
Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]
```

**Is there a way to drop/delete the temporary table that was created during the `optimize` process without having the mysql server running?**

Comment: If there's a .frm file associated with the temp table, you could probably just `rm` it, but I wouldn't suggest doing that without being sure that it's not going to cause other problems.

Comment: Move some files off the disk then fix mysql and move the files back. Or compress something then uncompress it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to drop/delete the temporary table that was created during the optimize process without having the mysql server running?

Unfortunately, no.

InnoDB is a very complex beast, and there's a lot of interplay between `ibdata`,`.ibd`, `ib_logfile`, and `.frm` files that means manual tinkering is, at best, extremely dangerous.

**Before you try anything, make a complete copy of all MySQL files to a remote server or another directory if at all possible**. When your situation is as delicate is this, it's easy to make a change that breaks the database irreparably.

Your best bet (as Boris mentioned above) is to try and **salvage some space** somewhere - anywhere. Compress or truncate some log files. Move some non-critical MyISAM tables (if you have any) off of the server until you have things at least partially under control. [Move a few .myd files to another directory and symlink them](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/symbolic-links.html) if you need to ([be really careful doing this to InnoDB files](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/symbolic-links.html)).

If you're *not* using [using **`innodb_file_per_table`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-multiple-tablespaces.html), then you're  going to end up with a giant ibdata file and no free disk space. [Rolando](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/877/rolandomysqldba) has given an [extensive answer about steps to resolve this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4056261/2293233), and you should follow that rather than the rest of these steps.

If you *are* [using **`innodb_file_per_table`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-multiple-tablespaces.html):

Once you have started MySQL successfully, you can check to see if the temporary table still exists (the easiest way to do this is to try `` desc `#sql-420a_65fb` ``, but there are also [more complex ways](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/11/29/beware-the-innodb-table-monitor/)).

If it still exists, you can drop it with:

```
drop table #mysql50##sql-420a_65fb
```

With `innodb_file_per_table` on, this will remove the temp table's .frm and .ibd files, and you will get some of your disk space back.

> I went into the console and ran the optimize command and since it's an InnoDB database it cloned the table to a temporary one (is that accurate?).

Yes, that's accurate. MySQL will create a temporary table with a name that looks something like `#sql-12a_345b`, and copy the data across it so that it's fresh and non-fragmented. Once it's complete, it would normally swap the tables around and then drop the old (fragmented) table).